# Why is liburing write performance lower than expected?

Tags: c++, linux, io-uring

## Problem Summary

I am working on a project that requires streaming data to disk at very high speeds on a single Linux server. An [fio](https://github.com/axboe/fio) benchmark using the command below shows that I should be able to get the desired write speeds (> 40 GB/s) using io_uring.

```
fio --name=seqwrite --rw=write --direct=1 --ioengine=io_uring --bs=128k --numjobs=4 --size=100G --runtime=300 --directory=/mnt/md0/ --iodepth=128 --buffered=0 --numa_cpu_nodes=0 --sqthread_poll=1  --hipri=1
```

However, I am not able to replicate this performance with my own code, which makes use of the [liburing](https://github.com/axboe/liburing) helper library for io_uring. My current write speed is about 9 GB/s. I suspect that the extra overhead of liburing might be the bottleneck, but I have a few questions to ask about my approach before I give up on the much-prettier liburing code.

## My approach

- Using [liburing](https://github.com/axboe/liburing)
- Utilizing the [submission queue polling](https://unixism.net/loti/tutorial/sq_poll.html) feature
- NOT queueing gather/scatter io requests with `writev()`, but rather queueing requests to use the normal `write()` function to write to disk. (tried gather / scatter IO requests, but this does not seem to have a major impact on my write speeds.)
- Multithreaded with one ring per thread

## Additional Information

- Running a simplified version of this code that makes no use of threading yielded similar results.
- My debugger shows that I am creating the number of threads specified in the `NUM_JOBS` macro. However, it does not tell me about threads that are created by the kernel for sq polling.
- My performance declines when running more than two threads
- The linux server has 96 CPUs to work with
- The data is being written to a RAID0 configuration
- I am using `bpftrace -e 'tracepoint:io_uring:io_uring_submit_sqe {printf("%s(%d)\n", comm, pid);}'` in a separate terminal, which shows that the kernel thread(s) dedicated to sq polling as active.
- I have verified that the data written to disk exactly matches what I expect it to be in size and contents.
- I have tried using the `IORING_SETUP_ATTACH_WQ` flag when setting up the rings. If anything, this slowed things down.
- I have tried various block sizes, 128k seems to be the sweet spot

## Questions

1. I expect that the kernel would spin up a single thread per ring to handle sq polling. However, I do not know how to verify this is actually happening. Can I assume that it is?
2. Why does my performance decrease when running more than two jobs? Is this due to contention between the threads for the file being written to? Maybe it is because there is actually only a single thread working on sq polling that might get bogged down handling requests from multiple rings?
3. Are there other flags or options I should be using that might help?
4. Is it time to bight the bullet and use direct io_uring calls?

## The Code

The code below is a simplified version that removes a lot of error handling code for the sake of brevity. However, the performance and function of this simplified version is the same as the full-featured code.

### The main function

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <liburing.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include "utilities.h"

#define NUM_JOBS 4 // number of single-ring threads
#define QUEUE_DEPTH 128 // size of each ring
#define IO_BLOCK_SIZE 128 * 1024 // write block size
#define WRITE_SIZE (IO_BLOCK_SIZE * 10000) // Total number of bytes to write
#define FILENAME  "/mnt/md0/test.txt" // File to write to

char incomingData[WRITE_SIZE]; // Will contain the data to write to disk

int main() 
{
    // Initialize variables
    std::vector<std::thread> threadPool;
    std::vector<io_uring*> ringPool;
    io_uring_params params;
    int fds[2];

    int bytesPerThread = WRITE_SIZE / NUM_JOBS;
    int bytesRemaining = WRITE_SIZE % NUM_JOBS;
    int bytesAssigned = 0;
    
    utils::generate_data(incomingData, WRITE_SIZE); // this just fills the incomingData buffer with known data

    // Open the file, store its descriptor
    fds[0] = open(FILENAME, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT);
    
    // initialize Rings
    ringPool.resize(NUM_JOBS);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_JOBS; i++)
    {
        io_uring* ring = new io_uring;

        // Configure the io_uring parameters and init the ring
        memset(&params, 0, sizeof(params));
        params.flags |= IORING_SETUP_SQPOLL;
        params.sq_thread_idle = 2000;
        io_uring_queue_init_params(QUEUE_DEPTH, ring, &params);
        io_uring_register_files(ring, fds, 1); // required for sq polling

        // Add the ring to the pool
        ringPool.at(i) = ring;
    }
    
    // Spin up threads to write to the file
    threadPool.resize(NUM_JOBS);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_JOBS; i++)
    {
        int bytesToAssign = (i != NUM_JOBS - 1) ? bytesPerThread : bytesPerThread + bytesRemaining;
        threadPool.at(i) = std::thread(writeToFile, 0, ringPool[i], incomingData + bytesAssigned, bytesToAssign, bytesAssigned);
        bytesAssigned += bytesToAssign;
    }

    // Wait for the threads to finish
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_JOBS; i++)
    {
        threadPool[i].join();
    }

    // Cleanup the rings
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_JOBS; i++)
    {
        io_uring_queue_exit(ringPool[i]);
    }

    // Close the file
    close(fds[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

### The writeToFile() function

```
void writeToFile(int fd, io_uring* ring, char* buffer, int size, int fileIndex)
{
    io_uring_cqe *cqe;
    io_uring_sqe *sqe;

    int bytesRemaining = size;
    int bytesToWrite;
    int bytesWritten = 0;
    int writesPending = 0;

    while (bytesRemaining || writesPending)
    {
        while(writesPending < QUEUE_DEPTH && bytesRemaining)
        {
            /* In this first inner loop,
             * Write up to QUEUE_DEPTH blocks to the submission queue
             */

            bytesToWrite = bytesRemaining > IO_BLOCK_SIZE ? IO_BLOCK_SIZE : bytesRemaining;
            sqe = io_uring_get_sqe(ring);
            if (!sqe) break; // if can't get a sqe, break out of the loop and wait for the next round
            io_uring_prep_write(sqe, fd, buffer + bytesWritten, bytesToWrite, fileIndex + bytesWritten);
            sqe->flags |= IOSQE_FIXED_FILE;
            
            writesPending++;
            bytesWritten += bytesToWrite;
            bytesRemaining -= bytesToWrite;
            if (bytesRemaining == 0) break;
        }

        io_uring_submit(ring);

        while(writesPending)
        {
            /* In this second inner loop,
             * Handle completions
             * Additional error handling removed for brevity
             * The functionality is the same as with errror handling in the case that nothing goes wrong
             */

            int status = io_uring_peek_cqe(ring, &cqe);
            if (status == -EAGAIN) break; // if no completions are available, break out of the loop and wait for the next round
            
            io_uring_cqe_seen(ring, cqe);

            writesPending--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing question! And you have a way to verify that your disks can write 40GB sustained? A short section about hardware setup might trigger thoughts for those with experience in these areas. Good luck!

Comment: I assume you're using compiler optimisations?

Comment: @shellter Thank you! I did verify that I am able to write to disk at 40GB sustained for at least 10 minutes using VIO. I do not know a whole lot about hardware, but here is what I do know:

There are two numa nodes. Each numa node has 48 physical cores (AMD) per socket and 6 nVME drives. The drivers are temporarily configured into 4 sets of 3-node RAID0 arrays, but eventually they will all be used for a single 12-node RAID0 array. When I say I am only getting 9 GB/s, I am extrapolating from the 2.25 GB/s that I am getting from my 3-node RAID0 array.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I do not know much about compiler optimizations, but I am getting the same performance in my debug builds as my release builds. Did you have something else in mind? 

Not sure if it is relevant, but I am compiling this on a machine running Ubuntu 22.04 using cMake and whatever the default compiler is (I do not specify the compiler in my cmakelists.txt files)

Comment: Did you take a look at the `fio` source code?

Comment: @PaulSanders I have looked at the `fio` source code. They are using the low level io_uring. This is why I suspect I might just have to bite the bullet and do the same. However, I am hoping to be able to avoid this, because fio's [`io_uring.c`](https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/master/engines/io_uring.c) source is over 1300 lines long and I would like to avoid this complexity if at all possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your fio example is using O_DIRECT, your own is doing buffered IO. That's quite a big change... Outside of that, you're also doing polled IO with fio, your example is not. Polled IO would set IORING_SETUP_IOPOLL and ensure that the underlying device has polling configured (see poll_queues=X for nvme). I suspect you end up doing IRQ driven IO anyway with fio, in case that isn't configured correctly to begin with.

A few more notes - fio also sets a few optimal flags, like defer taskrun and single issuer. If the kernel is new enough, that'll make a difference, though nothing crazy for this workload.

And finally, you're using registered files. This is fine obviously, and is a good optimization if you're reusing a file descriptor. But it's not a requirement for SQPOLL, that went away long ago.

In summary, the fio job you are running and the code you wrote do vastly different things. Not an apples to apples comparison.

Edit: fio job is also 4 threads writing to their own file, your example appears to be 4 threads writing to the same file. This will obviously make things worse, particularly since your example is buffered IO and you're just going to end up with a lot of contention on the inode lock because of that.

Comment: Thanks for this information -- it ultimately led to me getting the performance I need. I would like to add a little more detail for those like myself who are more new to io_uring and high-performance io. 

1. When using the O_DIRECT flag, the source of the data being written must be memory-aligned or you will get strange errors from io_uring.   
2. Enabling io polling doubled the write speed I was getting immediately.   
3. I returned to and updated my approach to scatter gather (allocating all iovec memory ahead of time and adding a memory manager). This doubled my write speed again